# Access private function in Node Module

Tags: node.js, module, commonjs

I have a function exposed through `export` in a node module I'm building.  I'd like to be able to have that function call an internal (private) function within the same module.

So far I have something like:

> someModule.js

```
var publicFunc = function(a, b) {
  var obj = {result: 'of some processing'};
  return privateFunc(obj);
}

var privateFunc = function(obj) {
  /* proccessing */
  return result;
}

exports.publicFunc = publicFunc;
```

When `publicFunc` calls `privateFunc` I get:

> Reference error: privateFunc is not defined;

Comment: "When I call privateFunc I get:..." - do you mean that return privateFunc(obj) is throwing the error or are you trying to call privateFunc from somewhere else other than inside publicFunc?

Comment: I try your code. it is fine. I can use publicFunc without any error.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to call a private function from this module?  Is it to test the module, or because you want to take advantage of the private function in your code?

Comment: @dylants I want certain methods and vars to be private.  I was attempting to hide the function from outside access and only allow access from other methods on the same module.  Make sense?  Should I instead use a constructor pattern, e.g. function Foo() { //define private method(s) };  And then add public functions via the prototype, e.g. Foo.publicFunc = function(){ /*blah*/ };  exports = Foo;

Comment: @veturi see my edited version.  The error comes when publicFunc makes the call to privateFunc.

Comment: It works for me apart from the fact that `result` is not defined, but the call is being made. This is exactly as I'd expect it to work.

Comment: @veturi, yes, @tadman's right, after your edits that should work fine (other than you'll need to define `result`, or perhaps you mean `obj.result`?).  It's very common to make internal/private functions in this way.  You can create an object and still use the same pattern -- defining a function outside of the object as a private function.  Either way, as long as you don't export it :)

Comment: @binarygiant, just declare privateFunc above publicFunc. Seems like its not able to resolve privateFunc as you have declared it later...

Answer (score 3):

Change your declarations to `function name(...` instead of `var name = function(...`

```
function publicFunc(a, b) {
  var obj = {result: 'of some processing'};
  return privateFunc(obj);
}

function privateFunc (obj) {
  /* proccessing */
  return result;
}

exports.publicFunc = publicFunc;
```